# kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]

Tags: centos, memory

My host machine is always stuck recently. and sometimes also black screen.

And when I start my host machine(CentOS 7.2), it records those information in the `/var/log/messages`:

[image]

The logs is below:

```
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.0: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 5: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:ff:12.4: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci_bus 0000:ff: Some PCI device resources are unassigned, try booting with pci=realloc
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 2: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 2: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 2: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 4: no space for [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 4: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000040]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 5: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.0: BAR 5: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 3: no space for [mem size 0x00000010]
Aug  8 16:29:18 localhost kernel: pci 0000:7f:12.4: BAR 3: failed to assign [mem size 0x00000010]
```

What's wrong with my host machine?

---

I use the `df -h` to check the disk:

```
[root@ha-node3 log]# df -h

/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  6.0G   45G   12% /
devtmpfs                 111G     0  111G    0% /dev
tmpfs                    111G     0  111G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    111G  9.3M  111G    1% /run
tmpfs                    111G     0  111G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdi1                494M  123M  371M   25% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  169G   33M  169G    1% /home
tmpfs                     23G     0   23G    0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: I've never seen `ff` or `7f` PCI bus numbers. Please edit question to include output of `lspci -n`. Guess so far: hardware failure on PCI root controller and/or PCI motherboard connections.

Comment: @dirkt The host machine is very high configuration hardware, have 16 slots.

Comment: The host machine is black screen now, and re-boot also is black screen, now I can not `lspci -n`, sorry.